Ktor HEAD Request Fails with "expected 0 bytes but received 20" Error
I'm trying to perform a simple HEAD request in Ktor (with OkHttp engine) to retrieve headers, but encountering an unexpected error. My Retrofit implementation works perfectly, but Ktor consistently throws an IOException.
Specific details:

Using Ktor 3.0.0-rc-1 with OkHttp engine on the Android Side
Attempting to make a HEAD request to retrieve specific header values
Error: java.io.IOException: expected 0 bytes but received 20
Retrofit code works without issues
I've tried multiple configuration approaches, including:

Disabling plugins
Creating fresh HttpClient
Configuring engine settings


I even used OkHttp directly and it worked: val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(true).build()
I am not trying to use neither OkHttp or Retrofit because the project is Multiplatform
Code snippet demonstrating the issue:

suspend fun getHeaderValue(header: String): String? {
    return client.head(url) {
        // Add headers
    }.headers[header]
}

Has anyone encountered similar issues with Ktor HEAD requests? Any insights into why this might be happening or how to resolve it?

Can you please share an endpoint to where you made the HEAD request? Can you please try to use the latest released version 3.0.1?

I am currently using the latest version 3.0.1
this is one of the endpoints:
it's just a mp3 file
I tried an online mp3
and the error didn't happen, maybe it has to do with dropbox ?
